# Find out all points within a shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Suppose I have the following (built-in) shapefile about the map of North Carolina:

```
    library(sf)
    library(igraph)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
        st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
        st_cast('POLYGON')

Simple feature collection with 108 features and 14 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32377 ymin: 33.88212 xmax: -75.45662 ymax: 36.58973
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                           geom
1   0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1      10  1364     0      19 POLYGON ((-81.47258 36.2344...
2   0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0      10   542     3      12 POLYGON ((-81.23971 36.3654...
3   0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5     208  3616     6     260 POLYGON ((-80.45614 36.2426...
4   0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1     123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-76.00863 36.3196...
4.1 0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1     123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-76.02682 36.5567...
4.2 0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1     123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-75.90164 36.5562...
5   0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9    1066  1606     3    1197 POLYGON ((-77.21736 36.2410...
6   0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7     954  1838     5    1237 POLYGON ((-76.74474 36.2339...
7   0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0     115   350     2     139 POLYGON ((-76.00863 36.3196...
8   0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0     254   594     2     371 POLYGON ((-76.56218 36.3406...
```

**My Question:** I would like to try and find out the geographical coordinates of "all points" that are contained within Ashe County (i.e. within a polygon).

I understand that of course this is not possible - so, I would like to try and find out the coordinates of 1000 evenly spaced points within Ashe County.

Here is what I tried so far:

The following code I think can be used to determine the outer perimeter of Ashe:

```
ashe <- nc[nc$NAME == "Ashe", ]
ashe_perimeter <- ashe$geom[[1]][[1]]
```

And this code here can be used to sample 1000 points from Ashe:

```
sample = st_sample(ashe, size = 1000)
```

Currently, my plan is to increase the size and hopefully cover enough area such that I have the coordinates of virtually all points within the interior and exterior (i.e. perimeter) of a given polygon.

**Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct?**

Thanks!

Comment: I think it depends WHY you need this - does it matter how the points are distributed, for example?  When you say "... cover enough area such that I have the coordinates of virtually all points within the interior and exterior (i.e. perimeter) of a given polygon." you presumably understand that that is an infinite list.  If you could define a resolution (points on a 1-foot grid, for example) it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When focusing on this part:

> I would like to try and find out the coordinates of 1000 evenly spaced points within Ashe County

, we could adjust sampling through `type` argument, defaults to `"random"`, so it would generate a non-random point grid. Let's try `regular`, for other types check [`?sf::st_sample`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_sample.html#arguments).

For "evenly spaced" part, a projected CRS would make bit more sense and `st_sample(... , type = "regular")` would treat longitude/latitude as planar coordinates anyway, so let's transform to UTM instead.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
ashe <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), 
                query = "SELECT geom FROM 'nc.gpkg' WHERE NAME = 'Ashe'",
                quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  # projected, UTM 17N https://epsg.io/3747
  st_transform(3747) %>% 
  st_geometry()


set.seed(123)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2), pty = "s") 

sample_random <- st_sample(ashe, size = 1000)
plot(ashe, sub = 'type = "random"')
plot(sample_random, pch = 20, cex = .1, add = TRUE)

sample_regular <- st_sample(ashe, size = 1000, type = "regular")
plot(ashe, sub = 'type = "regular"')
plot(sample_regular, pch = 20, cex = .1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Note that the size is approximation, here we ended up with 997 points:

```r
sample_regular
#> Geometry set for 997 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 434325.2 ymin: 4011028 xmax: 478041.2 ymax: 4049413
#> Projected CRS: NAD83(HARN) / UTM zone 17N
#> First 5 geometries:
#> POINT (456716.4 4011028)
#> POINT (457782.6 4011028)
#> POINT (458848.9 4011028)
#> POINT (455650.1 4012094)
#> POINT (456716.4 4012094)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Why did you choose crs = 3747 here?

Comment: As noted, `st_sample(... , type = "regular")` would treat longitude/latitude (i.e. crs 4326) as planar coordinates. It might not make that much of a difference with relatively small shapes like Ashe County, but for `nc` as a whole, latitudes range from 33.9 to 36.5. At lower lat, 1 degree along a parallel is ~92km while at the higher it's ~89km. For "evenly spaced"  points this kind of distortion might be a bit too much, hence the projected CRS like UTM. Feel free to pick some other, depending on preference and/or application.